# AS3 - Better AIR file selection windows?

Tags: actionscript-3, windows-7, air, dialog

When using `browseForOpen`, `browseForOpenMultiple` and `browseForSave` in Adobe AIR, the dialogue that comes up is a bit old-fashioned, and looks like a Windows XP dialog, despite me running Windows 7. It has the Windows 7 border, but I mean the buttons and such look a bit like that of Windows XP.
So I'm wondering, is there a way to make it look more "modern"?

Here's what I mean. Basically, I'm getting this:

[image: AIR Dialogue 1]

But I'd like to get something more like this:

[image: AIR Dialogue 2]

It's not strictly essential, but it's something that's been bothering me for a while and I'd just like to know if it's possible.

Comment: interesting, I'm sure that this dialogue is system dependent so there is no settings to style it in flash.

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela I'm not sure it is a system dialog. This is from the docs: `'The Open File dialog is not always displayed in front of windows that are "owned" by another window (windows that have a non-null owner property). To avoid window ordering issues, hide owned windows before calling this method.'` - which suggests it might be something within AIR. It looks like the old custom dialogs that Adobe desktop programs used to use instead of the OS one - my guess it it's something the AIR runtime itself generates. It certainly looks ugly enough to be Java...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently realised that this only happens when debugging an app. When you actually install the application and browse for files, the windows displays as it should.

I'm not sure if this has always been so and I only noticed it now, or perhaps that an AIR update has changed this.

Answer (score 0):

the only argument that is available for FileReference.browse() is typeFilter, so I'd assume you can't :P
it probably has to do with the implementation of the method onto the native OS. maybe a native extension could solve the case.

[http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#browse()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#browse%28%29)

Comment: I'm not talking about `FileReference.browse()`, rather `File.browseForOpen()`, `File.browseForOpenMultiple()`, and `File.browseForSave()`. These methods don't have many arguments either, but I was wondering if there was some other property or method anywhere that might have an effect on the dialogue.